# Replacement document on draft envelope

Tags: docusignapi

We are having some issue replacement documents using the docusign REST API.

The steps that we follow are, delete the documents, added the documents and adding al the tabs of the recipient for that document.

The follow ing is an example of the code that we use:

```
-- DELETE
https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/xx/envelopes/11111222223333344444/documents
DELETE
X-DocuSign-Authentication : {"Username": "XXXXXX","Password": "YYYYY","IntegratorKey": "ZZZZZZZZZ"}
{
    "documents": [
        {
             "documentId": "1"
        },
        {
             "documentId": "2"
        }
    ]
}

--ADD DOCUMENT
https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/xx/envelopes/11111222223333344444/documents
PUT
X-DocuSign-Authentication : {"Username": "XXXXXX","Password": "YYYYY","IntegratorKey": "ZZZZZZZZZ"}
Content-Type ** multipart/form-data; charset=UTF-8; boundary=111222333444
Accept ** application/json

--111222333444
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Disposition : form-data

{
    "documents": [
        {
             "name": "446_BBB.pdf",
             "documentId": "1",
             "order": "1",
             "documentFields": [
                 {
                     "name": "doctype",
                     "value": "cont"
                 }
             ]
        },
        {
             "name": "747_BBB.pdf",
             "documentId": "2",
             "order": "2",
             "documentFields": [
                 {
                     "name": "doctype",
                     "value": "cont"
                 }
             ]
        }
    ]
}
   --- doc bytes deletes

-- ADD TABS
https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/xx/envelopes/11111222223333344444/recipients/1/tabs
POST
X-DocuSign-Authentication : {"Username": "XXXXXX","Password": "YYYYY","IntegratorKey": "ZZZZZZZZZ"}
{
"signHereTabs": [
    {
        "anchorString": "<SIGNATURE_1/>",
        "anchorXOffset": "0",
        "anchorYOffset": "7",
        "documentId": "1",
        "pageNumber": "1"
    }
],
"textTabs": [
    {
        "documentId": "2",
        "pageNumber": "1",
        "xPosition": "109",
        "yPosition": "656",
        "tabLabel": "Name of depository",
        "disableAutoSize": "true",
        "name": "Name of depository",
        "required": "true",
        "width": "195",
        "maxLength": "33"
    }
],
"numberTabs": [
    {
        "documentId": "2",
        "pageNumber": "1",
        "xPosition": "420",
        "yPosition": "681",
        "tabLabel": "CC Account number",
        "disableAutoSize": "true",
        "name": "CC Account number",
        "required": "true",
        "width": "138",
        "maxLength": "16"
    }
],
"zipTabs": [
    {
        "documentId": "2",
        "pageNumber": "1",
        "xPosition": "197",
        "yPosition": "690",
        "tabLabel": "Depository zipcode",
        "disableAutoSize": "true",
        "name": "Depository zipcode",
        "required": "true",
        "width": "95",
        "maxLength": "5"
    }
]
```

}

The problem that we have are the following:

1. The documents doesn't keep the order specified
2. for the tabs, the process crreate 2 tabs of each type for the same recipient.

I really appreciate any help with this.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

> The documents doesn't keep the order specified

Make sure to reorder each of the existing documents as well. For example:

```
{
    "documents": [
        {
             "name": "446_BBB.pdf",
             "documentId": "1",
             "order": "1",
             "documentFields": [
                 {
                     "name": "doctype",
                     "value": "cont"
                 }
             ]
        },
        {
             "name": "747_BBB.pdf",
             "documentId": "2",
             "order": "2",
             "documentFields": [
                 {
                     "name": "doctype",
                     "value": "cont"
                 }
             ]
        },
        {
             "documentId": "3",
             "order": "3"
        }
    ]
}
```

> for the tabs, the process crreate 2 tabs of each type for the same recipient.

Seems like a bug (will let you know otherwise or when fixed). To workaround this issue you can split the last API request into two separate requests, one that contains the `signHereTabs` only, and another for all the other tabs.